# errors with Discord.py Animate emoji saying None

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Here is my code:

```
@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(20, 1, commands.BucketType.user)
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"<a:NM_VerifiedBlack:711146061544292372>")
```

It outputs as :NM_VerifiedBlack: not the emoji

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the bot doesn't output the emoji you want it to is because that the discord bot isn't in the server with the emoji.

All you need to do is to invite the discord bot to the server with the `<a:NM_VerifiedBlack:711146061544292372>` emoji. Then, restart your bot and run the command again.